# como comparar si una fecha es menor a otra y que esto me cuente con PHP

Tags: php

Hola muy buenas tardes para todos, un saludo.

Estoy tratando de comparar los registros en donde la fechacumpli sea menor o igual a la fecha de hoy deberia de contarme los registros, pero no me funciona. no me trae información queda en 0 y si tengo un registro con esa condición.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

$contador = 0;
$atrasa=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `detalle_entrega` where estatus='Completado'");
while($seatraso = mysqli_fetch_array($atrasa)){
    
    
    $fechacrea = $seatraso['fechacrea'];
    $fechacumpli = $seatraso['fechacumpli'];
    
    
    $hoy=date("Y-m-d");
    
    $vone = strtotime($fechacumpli);
    $vtwo = strtotime($hoy); 
    

    if ($vone <= $vtwo){
    
        echo $contador++;
        
    }else{
        
        echo "0";
    }
    
}
?>
```

No se que estoy haciendo mal, cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me puede ser de gran utilidad.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Si ambos datos están en formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, con solo comparar los strings es suficiente: `var_dump('2022-05-25' > '2022-06-01'); // false` y por el contrario: `var_dump('2022-06-01' > '2022-05-25'); // true`

Comment: Hola @aeprotugal ya lo intente asi y no funciono por esa razón agregue los strtotime a las variables de fecha, pero tampoco me funciona.

Comment: ¿De qué tipo es la columna en la base de datos y en qué formato están guardados los datos? ¿La fecha incluye también la hora? Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta, poniendo, si es posible, un ejemplo de los datos que existen.

Comment: La fecha se esta guardando como tipo varchar y con un formato de año/mes/día. la hora se guarda en otro campo diferente.

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($seatraso);` dentro del `while` y dinos qué valores vienen en tu consulta. Sin ver datos reales no podremos ayudarte, ni siquiera sabemos si tu consulta funciona, qué datos trae, bajo qué keys vienen, etc. No estamos delante de tu pantalla para ver las cosas. Pulsa en [edit] y completa tu pregunta.